# How to implement and run a docker container over SSL

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an angular application that I have already deployed on a Centos server with docker the URL is running on **HTTP**. I want to secure the domain so as it will be on **HTTPS**. I would really appreciate it if I could get a suggestion or link sources for such kind of implementation. In the meantime, I will be trying to follow up on this [link](https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71)

**Folder Structure**

```
frontend/
├── nginx/
│   ├── default.conf
│   
├── src/
│   
│   
└── dist/
|   
|
└── Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest as node

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install 

RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY  --from=node /app/nginx/*  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=node /app/dist/e-county /usr/share/nginx/htm
```

Comment: Any luck with getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to **configure nginx to use SSL**.

A nice reference can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins).

Here is the jist of it:

```
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name jenkins.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}
```